# Docx comparing and editing?

Tags: python, vba, ms-word

I have been doing a lot of research around here and reddit but still can not find a solution to my issue. Basically at work they have asked me to code a script that will allow me to compare the text of to Microsoft word docs. If the the specific text I need to compare in doc1 differed from doc2 then I need to replace the text in doc2 with that of doc1. This will need to be done in Python or VBA for word.

I have been considering using the docx python module along with regex to find the specific patterns I need which will be in this example format:

doc1 will contain:Task12 7.120 Aircraft 7.11 VFR Ops

doc2 will contain: 7.120 Aircraft  NAC12

NAC12 is the same as Task12. So I need to pick these above examples out of a lot of text and then make sure that doc2 is the same as doc1 and if not replace the text with that of doc1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word has a feature built-in that can do what you are after – the *Combine* command:

[image: Screenshot of Word Combine command in the Office Ribbon]

Here is a VBA macro recorded with Word's macro recorder using that command to merge two documents:

```
Sub MergeDocuments(file1 As String, file2 As String)

    ' Merge the documents
    Application.MergeDocuments OriginalDocument:=Documents(file1), _
        RevisedDocument:=Documents(file2), Destination:= _
        wdCompareDestinationNew, Granularity:=wdGranularityWordLevel, _
        CompareFormatting:=True, CompareCaseChanges:=True, CompareWhitespace:= _
        True, CompareTables:=True, CompareHeaders:=True, CompareFootnotes:=True, _
        CompareTextboxes:=True, CompareFields:=True, CompareComments:=True, _
        CompareMoves:=True, OriginalAuthor:="Author1", RevisedAuthor:="Author2", _
        FormatFrom:=wdMergeFormatFromPrompt

    ActiveWindow.ShowSourceDocuments = wdShowSourceDocumentsBoth

    ' Accept the revisions and stop tracking changes
    ActiveDocument.AcceptAllRevisions
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False

    If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial = wdPaneNone Then
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
    Else
        ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPrintView
    End If

End Sub
```